# recursive function print in the other way

Tags: c++, recursion, numbers

Im trying to program a recursive function which will allow me to print each digit of a number on a separate line like this :

```
int decompose(int n){
  if(n%10){
    cout << n%10 << endl; 
    return decompose(n/10);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    decompose(2345);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
5
4
3
2
```

PROBLEM : I wanted to print on the other way

```
2
3
4
5
```

How to do that ?

Comment: Try putting the `cout` call after the recursive call.

Comment: Since your are printing the number in `decompose()` function change it's return type from `int` to `void`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void decompose(int n){
  if (n>=10)           //Call decompose if there are "more" digits in the number to print
     decompose(n/10);  
  cout << n%10 << endl;  //print the last digit of n
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    decompose(2345);
}
```

Since you decompose first and print later in a number like 2345 the stack will look like this:

main()

decompose(2345)

decompose(234)

decompose(23)

decompose(2)

then as we start returning each call will print the last digit: 2 -> 3 ->4 ->5

NOTE: In your version you use the condition `if(n%10){}` this will be false whenever n is a multiple of 10. It means the versions with it will stop the moment a 0 digit is reached.

Try them with inputs such as `23450` or `23045`

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you can just put the cout after the recursive calls and it will print in reverse order.

More generally, though, you can't always print directly in reverse order or it is not evident how to do it: in such cases you could append the output at each step to a vector of string and, once out of the function, print the vector in reverse order.
It's slightly less efficient and requires to keep in memory all the output at each step but, when these factors are negligible, it's easy to implement and understand.